# XML into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I have an XML file and I would like to parse it into a table. (Pandas dataframe)
Below is just a sample of the XML file. Those are only two of the records.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
   <C13_335010X321A1_837Y6>
      <BHT_BeginningOfHierarchicalTransaction>
         <BHT01__HierarchicalStructureCode>0011</BHT01__HierarchicalStructureCode>
         <BHT02__TransactionSetPurposeCode>00</BHT02__TransactionSetPurposeCode>
         <BHT03__OriginatorApplicationTransactionIdentifier>513513TR</BHT03__OriginatorApplicationTransactionIdentifier>
         <BHT04__TransactionSetCreationDate>20200212</BHT04__TransactionSetCreationDate>
         <BHT05__TransactionSetCreationTime>1287</BHT05__TransactionSetCreationTime>
         <BHT06__ClaimOrEncounterIdentifier>DD</BHT06__ClaimOrEncounterIdentifier>
      </BHT_BeginningOfHierarchicalTransaction>
      <Loop_1000A>
         <NM1_SubmitterName_1000A>
            <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>27</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
            <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>9</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
            <NM103__SubmitterLastOrOrganizationName>AAA</NM103__SubmitterLastOrOrganizationName>
            <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>22</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
            <NM109__SubmitterIdentifier>55555500</NM109__SubmitterIdentifier>
         </NM1_SubmitterName_1000A>
         <PER_SubmitterEDIContactInformation_1000A>
            <PER01__ContactFunctionCode>LK</PER01__ContactFunctionCode>
            <PER02__SubmitterContactName>John Smith</PER02__SubmitterContactName>
            <PER03__CommunicationNumberQualifier>WW</PER03__CommunicationNumberQualifier>
            <PER04__CommunicationNumber>2132220011</PER04__CommunicationNumber>
            <PER05__CommunicationNumberQualifier>DD</PER05__CommunicationNumberQualifier>
            <PER06__CommunicationNumber>DD_2@GMAIL.COM</PER06__CommunicationNumber>
         </PER_SubmitterEDIContactInformation_1000A>
      </Loop_1000A>
      <Loop_1000B>
         <NM1_ReceiverName_1000B>
            <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>21</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
            <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>0</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
            <NM103__ReceiverName>AAA</NM103__ReceiverName>
            <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>32</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
            <NM109__ReceiverPrimaryIdentifier>2514521</NM109__ReceiverPrimaryIdentifier>
         </NM1_ReceiverName_1000B>
      </Loop_1000B>
      <Loop_2000A>
         <HL_BillingProviderHierarchicalLevel_2000A>
            <HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>32</HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>
            <HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>54</HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>
            <HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>32</HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>
         </HL_BillingProviderHierarchicalLevel_2000A>
         <Loop_2010AA>
            <NM1_BillingProviderName_2010AA>
               <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>54</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
               <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>21</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
               <NM103__BillingProviderLastOrOrganizationalName>AAA</NM103__BillingProviderLastOrOrganizationalName>
               <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>XX</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
               <NM109__BillingProviderIdentifier>515151325</NM109__BillingProviderIdentifier>
            </NM1_BillingProviderName_2010AA>
            <N3_BillingProviderAddress_2010AA>
               <N301__BillingProviderAddressLine>214 SS STREET</N301__BillingProviderAddressLine>
            </N3_BillingProviderAddress_2010AA>
            <N4_BillingProviderCityStateZIPCode_2010AA>
               <N401__BillingProviderCityName>LA</N401__BillingProviderCityName>
               <N402__BillingProviderStateOrProvinceCode>CA</N402__BillingProviderStateOrProvinceCode>
               <N403__BillingProviderPostalZoneOrZIPCode>93500</N403__BillingProviderPostalZoneOrZIPCode>
            </N4_BillingProviderCityStateZIPCode_2010AA>
            <REF_BillingProviderTaxIdentification_2010AA>
               <REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>OI</REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
               <REF02__BillingProviderTaxIdentificationNumber>5135151315</REF02__BillingProviderTaxIdentificationNumber>
            </REF_BillingProviderTaxIdentification_2010AA>
         </Loop_2010AA>
         <Loop_2000B>
            <HL_SubscriberHierarchicalLevel_2000B>
               <HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>5</HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>
               <HL02__HierarchicalParentIDNumber>5</HL02__HierarchicalParentIDNumber>
               <HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>55</HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>
               <HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>5</HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>
            </HL_SubscriberHierarchicalLevel_2000B>
            <SBR_SubscriberInformation_2000B>
               <SBR01__PayerResponsibilitySequenceNumberCode>L</SBR01__PayerResponsibilitySequenceNumberCode>
               <SBR02__IndividualRelationshipCode>32</SBR02__IndividualRelationshipCode>
               <SBR03__SubscriberGroupOrPolicyNumber>252525Z125</SBR03__SubscriberGroupOrPolicyNumber>
               <SBR09__ClaimFilingIndicatorCode>NM</SBR09__ClaimFilingIndicatorCode>
            </SBR_SubscriberInformation_2000B>
            <Loop_2010BA>
               <NM1_SubscriberName_2010BA>
                  <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>DCX</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
                  <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>5</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
                  <NM103__SubscriberLastName>SMITH</NM103__SubscriberLastName>
                  <NM104__SubscriberFirstName>JOHN</NM104__SubscriberFirstName>
                  <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>CA</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
                  <NM109__SubscriberPrimaryIdentifier>3656361.</NM109__SubscriberPrimaryIdentifier>
               </NM1_SubscriberName_2010BA>
               <N3_SubscriberAddress_2010BA>
                  <N301__SubscriberAddressLine>111 STREET</N301__SubscriberAddressLine>
               </N3_SubscriberAddress_2010BA>
               <N4_SubscriberCityStateZIPCode_2010BA>
                  <N401__SubscriberCityName>LA</N401__SubscriberCityName>
                  <N402__SubscriberStateCode>CA</N402__SubscriberStateCode>
                  <N403__SubscriberPostalZoneOrZIPCode>93000</N403__SubscriberPostalZoneOrZIPCode>
               </N4_SubscriberCityStateZIPCode_2010BA>
               <DMG_SubscriberDemographicInformation_2010BA>
                  <DMG01__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>K5</DMG01__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>
                  <DMG02__SubscriberBirthDate>19851010</DMG02__SubscriberBirthDate>
                  <DMG03__SubscriberGenderCode>U</DMG03__SubscriberGenderCode>
               </DMG_SubscriberDemographicInformation_2010BA>
            </Loop_2010BA>
            <Loop_2010BB>
               <NM1_PayerName_2010BB>
                  <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>FF</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
                  <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>3</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
                  <NM103__PayerName>AAA</NM103__PayerName>
                  <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>GF</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
                  <NM109__PayerIdentifier>32514</NM109__PayerIdentifier>
               </NM1_PayerName_2010BB>
            </Loop_2010BB>
            <Loop_2300>
               <CLM_ClaimInformation_2300>
                  <CLM01__PatientControlNumber>5413</CLM01__PatientControlNumber>
                  <CLM02__TotalClaimChargeAmount>651</CLM02__TotalClaimChargeAmount>
                  <CLM05_HealthCareServiceLocationInformation_2300>
                     <CLM05_01_PlaceOfServiceCode>13</CLM05_01_PlaceOfServiceCode>
                     <CLM05_02_FacilityCodeQualifier>D</CLM05_02_FacilityCodeQualifier>
                     <CLM05_03_ClaimFrequencyCode>3</CLM05_03_ClaimFrequencyCode>
                  </CLM05_HealthCareServiceLocationInformation_2300>
                  <CLM06__ProviderOrSupplierSignatureIndicator>N</CLM06__ProviderOrSupplierSignatureIndicator>
                  <CLM07__AssignmentOrPlanParticipationCode>R</CLM07__AssignmentOrPlanParticipationCode>
                  <CLM08__BenefitsAssignmentCertificationIndicator>N</CLM08__BenefitsAssignmentCertificationIndicator>
                  <CLM09__ReleaseOfInformationCode>N</CLM09__ReleaseOfInformationCode>
                  <CLM10__PatientSignatureSourceCode>X</CLM10__PatientSignatureSourceCode>
               </CLM_ClaimInformation_2300>
               <REF_ClaimIdentifierForTransmissionIntermediaries_2300>
                  <REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>J1</REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
                  <REF02__ValueAddedNetworkTraceNumber>FVC2514543254</REF02__ValueAddedNetworkTraceNumber>
               </REF_ClaimIdentifierForTransmissionIntermediaries_2300>
               <HI_HealthCareDiagnosisCode_2300>
                  <HI01_HealthCareCodeInformation_2300>
                     <HI01_01_DiagnosisTypeCode>CCC</HI01_01_DiagnosisTypeCode>
                     <HI01_02_DiagnosisCode>N111</HI01_02_DiagnosisCode>
                  </HI01_HealthCareCodeInformation_2300>
               </HI_HealthCareDiagnosisCode_2300>
               <Loop_2310B>
                  <NM1_RenderingProviderName_2310B>
                     <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>32</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
                     <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>2</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
                     <NM103__RenderingProviderLastOrOrganizationName>JOHN</NM103__RenderingProviderLastOrOrganizationName>
                     <NM104__RenderingProviderFirstName>SMITH</NM104__RenderingProviderFirstName>
                     <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>TT</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
                     <NM109__RenderingProviderIdentifier>25431251</NM109__RenderingProviderIdentifier>
                  </NM1_RenderingProviderName_2310B>
                  <PRV_RenderingProviderSpecialtyInformation_2310B>
                     <PRV01__ProviderCode>TR</PRV01__ProviderCode>
                     <PRV02__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>VFD</PRV02__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
                     <PRV03__ProviderTaxonomyCode>135454353L</PRV03__ProviderTaxonomyCode>
                  </PRV_RenderingProviderSpecialtyInformation_2310B>
               </Loop_2310B>
               <Loop_2400>
                  <LX_ServiceLineNumber_2400>
                     <LX01__AssignedNumber>2</LX01__AssignedNumber>
                  </LX_ServiceLineNumber_2400>
                  <SV1_ProfessionalService_2400>
                     <SV101_CompositeMedicalProcedureIdentifier_2400>
                        <SV101_01_ProductOrServiceIDQualifier>EE</SV101_01_ProductOrServiceIDQualifier>
                        <SV101_02_ProcedureCode>99999</SV101_02_ProcedureCode>
                        <SV101_07_Description>BLOOD</SV101_07_Description>
                     </SV101_CompositeMedicalProcedureIdentifier_2400>
                     <SV102__LineItemChargeAmount>200</SV102__LineItemChargeAmount>
                     <SV103__UnitOrBasisForMeasurementCode>PP</SV103__UnitOrBasisForMeasurementCode>
                     <SV104__ServiceUnitCount>3.5</SV104__ServiceUnitCount>
                     <SV107_CompositeDiagnosisCodePointer_2400>
                        <SV107_01_DiagnosisCodePointer>2</SV107_01_DiagnosisCodePointer>
                     </SV107_CompositeDiagnosisCodePointer_2400>
                  </SV1_ProfessionalService_2400>
                  <DTP_DateServiceDate_2400>
                     <DTP01__DateTimeQualifier>654</DTP01__DateTimeQualifier>
                     <DTP02__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>U8</DTP02__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>
                     <DTP03__ServiceDate>20191010</DTP03__ServiceDate>
                  </DTP_DateServiceDate_2400>
                  <REF_LineItemControlNumber_2400>
                     <REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>5F</REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
                     <REF02__LineItemControlNumber>DDD.32.123</REF02__LineItemControlNumber>
                  </REF_LineItemControlNumber_2400>
               </Loop_2400>
            </Loop_2300>
         </Loop_2000B>
      </Loop_2000A>
   </C13_335010X321A1_837Y6>
   <C13_335010X321A1_837Y6>
      <BHT_BeginningOfHierarchicalTransaction>
         <BHT01__HierarchicalStructureCode>0011</BHT01__HierarchicalStructureCode>
         <BHT02__TransactionSetPurposeCode>00</BHT02__TransactionSetPurposeCode>
         <BHT03__OriginatorApplicationTransactionIdentifier>513513TR</BHT03__OriginatorApplicationTransactionIdentifier>
         <BHT04__TransactionSetCreationDate>20200212</BHT04__TransactionSetCreationDate>
         <BHT05__TransactionSetCreationTime>1287</BHT05__TransactionSetCreationTime>
         <BHT06__ClaimOrEncounterIdentifier>DD</BHT06__ClaimOrEncounterIdentifier>
      </BHT_BeginningOfHierarchicalTransaction>
      <Loop_1000A>
         <NM1_SubmitterName_1000A>
            <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>27</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
            <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>9</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
            <NM103__SubmitterLastOrOrganizationName>AAA</NM103__SubmitterLastOrOrganizationName>
            <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>22</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
            <NM109__SubmitterIdentifier>55555500</NM109__SubmitterIdentifier>
         </NM1_SubmitterName_1000A>
         <PER_SubmitterEDIContactInformation_1000A>
            <PER01__ContactFunctionCode>LK</PER01__ContactFunctionCode>
            <PER02__SubmitterContactName>John Smith</PER02__SubmitterContactName>
            <PER03__CommunicationNumberQualifier>WW</PER03__CommunicationNumberQualifier>
            <PER04__CommunicationNumber>2132220011</PER04__CommunicationNumber>
            <PER05__CommunicationNumberQualifier>DD</PER05__CommunicationNumberQualifier>
            <PER06__CommunicationNumber>DD_2@GMAIL.COM</PER06__CommunicationNumber>
         </PER_SubmitterEDIContactInformation_1000A>
      </Loop_1000A>
      <Loop_1000B>
         <NM1_ReceiverName_1000B>
            <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>21</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
            <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>0</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
            <NM103__ReceiverName>AAA</NM103__ReceiverName>
            <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>32</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
            <NM109__ReceiverPrimaryIdentifier>2514521</NM109__ReceiverPrimaryIdentifier>
         </NM1_ReceiverName_1000B>
      </Loop_1000B>
      <Loop_2000A>
         <HL_BillingProviderHierarchicalLevel_2000A>
            <HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>32</HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>
            <HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>54</HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>
            <HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>32</HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>
         </HL_BillingProviderHierarchicalLevel_2000A>
         <Loop_2010AA>
            <NM1_BillingProviderName_2010AA>
               <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>54</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
               <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>21</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
               <NM103__BillingProviderLastOrOrganizationalName>AAA</NM103__BillingProviderLastOrOrganizationalName>
               <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>XX</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
               <NM109__BillingProviderIdentifier>515151325</NM109__BillingProviderIdentifier>
            </NM1_BillingProviderName_2010AA>
            <N3_BillingProviderAddress_2010AA>
               <N301__BillingProviderAddressLine>214 SS STREET</N301__BillingProviderAddressLine>
            </N3_BillingProviderAddress_2010AA>
            <N4_BillingProviderCityStateZIPCode_2010AA>
               <N401__BillingProviderCityName>LA</N401__BillingProviderCityName>
               <N402__BillingProviderStateOrProvinceCode>CA</N402__BillingProviderStateOrProvinceCode>
               <N403__BillingProviderPostalZoneOrZIPCode>93500</N403__BillingProviderPostalZoneOrZIPCode>
            </N4_BillingProviderCityStateZIPCode_2010AA>
            <REF_BillingProviderTaxIdentification_2010AA>
               <REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>OI</REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
               <REF02__BillingProviderTaxIdentificationNumber>5135151315</REF02__BillingProviderTaxIdentificationNumber>
            </REF_BillingProviderTaxIdentification_2010AA>
         </Loop_2010AA>
         <Loop_2000B>
            <HL_SubscriberHierarchicalLevel_2000B>
               <HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>5</HL01__HierarchicalIDNumber>
               <HL02__HierarchicalParentIDNumber>5</HL02__HierarchicalParentIDNumber>
               <HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>55</HL03__HierarchicalLevelCode>
               <HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>5</HL04__HierarchicalChildCode>
            </HL_SubscriberHierarchicalLevel_2000B>
            <SBR_SubscriberInformation_2000B>
               <SBR01__PayerResponsibilitySequenceNumberCode>L</SBR01__PayerResponsibilitySequenceNumberCode>
               <SBR02__IndividualRelationshipCode>32</SBR02__IndividualRelationshipCode>
               <SBR03__SubscriberGroupOrPolicyNumber>252525Z125</SBR03__SubscriberGroupOrPolicyNumber>
               <SBR09__ClaimFilingIndicatorCode>NM</SBR09__ClaimFilingIndicatorCode>
            </SBR_SubscriberInformation_2000B>
            <Loop_2010BA>
               <NM1_SubscriberName_2010BA>
                  <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>DCX</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
                  <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>5</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
                  <NM103__SubscriberLastName>SMITH</NM103__SubscriberLastName>
                  <NM104__SubscriberFirstName>JOHN</NM104__SubscriberFirstName>
                  <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>CA</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
                  <NM109__SubscriberPrimaryIdentifier>3656361.</NM109__SubscriberPrimaryIdentifier>
               </NM1_SubscriberName_2010BA>
               <N3_SubscriberAddress_2010BA>
                  <N301__SubscriberAddressLine>111 STREET</N301__SubscriberAddressLine>
               </N3_SubscriberAddress_2010BA>
               <N4_SubscriberCityStateZIPCode_2010BA>
                  <N401__SubscriberCityName>LA</N401__SubscriberCityName>
                  <N402__SubscriberStateCode>CA</N402__SubscriberStateCode>
                  <N403__SubscriberPostalZoneOrZIPCode>93000</N403__SubscriberPostalZoneOrZIPCode>
               </N4_SubscriberCityStateZIPCode_2010BA>
               <DMG_SubscriberDemographicInformation_2010BA>
                  <DMG01__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>K5</DMG01__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>
                  <DMG02__SubscriberBirthDate>19851010</DMG02__SubscriberBirthDate>
                  <DMG03__SubscriberGenderCode>U</DMG03__SubscriberGenderCode>
               </DMG_SubscriberDemographicInformation_2010BA>
            </Loop_2010BA>
            <Loop_2010BB>
               <NM1_PayerName_2010BB>
                  <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>FF</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
                  <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>3</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
                  <NM103__PayerName>AAA</NM103__PayerName>
                  <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>GF</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
                  <NM109__PayerIdentifier>32514</NM109__PayerIdentifier>
               </NM1_PayerName_2010BB>
            </Loop_2010BB>
            <Loop_2300>
               <CLM_ClaimInformation_2300>
                  <CLM01__PatientControlNumber>5413</CLM01__PatientControlNumber>
                  <CLM02__TotalClaimChargeAmount>651</CLM02__TotalClaimChargeAmount>
                  <CLM05_HealthCareServiceLocationInformation_2300>
                     <CLM05_01_PlaceOfServiceCode>13</CLM05_01_PlaceOfServiceCode>
                     <CLM05_02_FacilityCodeQualifier>D</CLM05_02_FacilityCodeQualifier>
                     <CLM05_03_ClaimFrequencyCode>3</CLM05_03_ClaimFrequencyCode>
                  </CLM05_HealthCareServiceLocationInformation_2300>
                  <CLM06__ProviderOrSupplierSignatureIndicator>N</CLM06__ProviderOrSupplierSignatureIndicator>
                  <CLM07__AssignmentOrPlanParticipationCode>R</CLM07__AssignmentOrPlanParticipationCode>
                  <CLM08__BenefitsAssignmentCertificationIndicator>N</CLM08__BenefitsAssignmentCertificationIndicator>
                  <CLM09__ReleaseOfInformationCode>N</CLM09__ReleaseOfInformationCode>
                  <CLM10__PatientSignatureSourceCode>X</CLM10__PatientSignatureSourceCode>
               </CLM_ClaimInformation_2300>
               <REF_ClaimIdentifierForTransmissionIntermediaries_2300>
                  <REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>J1</REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
                  <REF02__ValueAddedNetworkTraceNumber>FVC2514543254</REF02__ValueAddedNetworkTraceNumber>
               </REF_ClaimIdentifierForTransmissionIntermediaries_2300>
               <HI_HealthCareDiagnosisCode_2300>
                  <HI01_HealthCareCodeInformation_2300>
                     <HI01_01_DiagnosisTypeCode>CCC</HI01_01_DiagnosisTypeCode>
                     <HI01_02_DiagnosisCode>N111</HI01_02_DiagnosisCode>
                  </HI01_HealthCareCodeInformation_2300>
               </HI_HealthCareDiagnosisCode_2300>
               <Loop_2310B>
                  <NM1_RenderingProviderName_2310B>
                     <NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>32</NM101__EntityIdentifierCode>
                     <NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>2</NM102__EntityTypeQualifier>
                     <NM103__RenderingProviderLastOrOrganizationName>JOHN</NM103__RenderingProviderLastOrOrganizationName>
                     <NM104__RenderingProviderFirstName>SMITH</NM104__RenderingProviderFirstName>
                     <NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>TT</NM108__IdentificationCodeQualifier>
                     <NM109__RenderingProviderIdentifier>25431251</NM109__RenderingProviderIdentifier>
                  </NM1_RenderingProviderName_2310B>
                  <PRV_RenderingProviderSpecialtyInformation_2310B>
                     <PRV01__ProviderCode>TR</PRV01__ProviderCode>
                     <PRV02__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>VFD</PRV02__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
                     <PRV03__ProviderTaxonomyCode>135454353L</PRV03__ProviderTaxonomyCode>
                  </PRV_RenderingProviderSpecialtyInformation_2310B>
               </Loop_2310B>
               <Loop_2400>
                  <LX_ServiceLineNumber_2400>
                     <LX01__AssignedNumber>2</LX01__AssignedNumber>
                  </LX_ServiceLineNumber_2400>
                  <SV1_ProfessionalService_2400>
                     <SV101_CompositeMedicalProcedureIdentifier_2400>
                        <SV101_01_ProductOrServiceIDQualifier>EE</SV101_01_ProductOrServiceIDQualifier>
                        <SV101_02_ProcedureCode>99999</SV101_02_ProcedureCode>
                        <SV101_07_Description>BLOOD</SV101_07_Description>
                     </SV101_CompositeMedicalProcedureIdentifier_2400>
                     <SV102__LineItemChargeAmount>200</SV102__LineItemChargeAmount>
                     <SV103__UnitOrBasisForMeasurementCode>PP</SV103__UnitOrBasisForMeasurementCode>
                     <SV104__ServiceUnitCount>3.5</SV104__ServiceUnitCount>
                     <SV107_CompositeDiagnosisCodePointer_2400>
                        <SV107_01_DiagnosisCodePointer>2</SV107_01_DiagnosisCodePointer>
                     </SV107_CompositeDiagnosisCodePointer_2400>
                  </SV1_ProfessionalService_2400>
                  <DTP_DateServiceDate_2400>
                     <DTP01__DateTimeQualifier>654</DTP01__DateTimeQualifier>
                     <DTP02__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>U8</DTP02__DateTimePeriodFormatQualifier>
                     <DTP03__ServiceDate>20191010</DTP03__ServiceDate>
                  </DTP_DateServiceDate_2400>
                  <REF_LineItemControlNumber_2400>
                     <REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>5F</REF01__ReferenceIdentificationQualifier>
                     <REF02__LineItemControlNumber>DDD.32.123</REF02__LineItemControlNumber>
                  </REF_LineItemControlNumber_2400>
               </Loop_2400>
            </Loop_2300>
         </Loop_2000B>
      </Loop_2000A>
   </C13_335010X321A1_837Y6>
</file>
```

These have to be in two rows, I am using the following python code to convert it into panda data frame, but I am getting empty data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def xml_file(file):
    columns = file.attrib
    for xml in file.iter('C13_335010X321A1_837Y6'):
        file_dict = columns.copy()
        file_dict.update(xml.attrib)
        yield file_dict

tree = et.parse(r"C:\Users\Desktop\test1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
df = pd.DataFrame(list(xml_file(root)))
```

Comment: What should the table structure be?

Comment: pandas has a `read_xml` method.

Comment: Unlike a data frame, XML is not a two dimensional construct. So what exact nodes do you need to parse into rows and columns? There are many nested nodes under `C13_335010X321A1_837Y6`.